# How to tell if I need to put present continuous or past simple in a sentence

Tags: present-continuous

For example:

> I was getting ready.
>
> I got ready.

When do I use which?

Comment: I think you mean 'past continuous'. Please confirm.

Comment: "I was getting ready to go out when the phone rang" (you hadn't finished). "I got ready and went out" (you finished doing so).

Comment: What's the context?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. It depends on what you **want to say**.

Answer (score 0):

Let's see these examples:

Yesterday when **I was going** to my office, I saw one of my friends.

When you **`start an action in the past`** but **`another action happend during the first one`** (you couldn't finish first action) you have to use past continiuous.

Yesterday **I went** to my office.

When you **`start an action in the past`** and you were **`successful to finish`** that(nothing happend betweent the first action), you have to use simple past.